# Grabbing cookie set after post with httpWebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to grab the cookie that is set in the response after a successful POST.  How can I grab the cookies from the result?

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://rtchatserver");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            using (var postHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(postHandler) {BaseAddress = baseAddress})
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", "bar"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "bazinga"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__RequestVerificationToken", token),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("returnUrl", "http://google.com"),
                });
                cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, responseCookies.FirstOrDefault());
                var result = client.PostAsync("/account/login", content).Result;

                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CookieContainer.GetCookies method:

```
var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://rtchatserver/account/login"));
```

Comment: The cookie is set as the response to a successful POST though - will this still work?